# При открытии книги переход к ячейке с текущей датой

Tags: excel, vba, макрос

Нужен макрос, который при запуске файла или при запуске макроса будет автоматически ставить курсор на ячейку значение которой соответствует текущей дате.

В столбце все ячейки имею значение дата в формате `дд МММ___ДДД`. Диапазон ячеек `B4:B290`

Спасибо

Comment: Данный ресурс - это не сайт с ГДЗ. Нужен готовый макрос - заказывайте у фрилансеров и платите за это деньги. Хотите ответа на вопрос - попробуйте решить проблему  самостоятельно, покажите ваш вариант и скажите, что не работает.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В модуль `ЭтаКнига`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim c As Range

    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        For Each c In .Range("B4:B290")
            If c.Value = Date Then
                .Activate: c.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

Если в ячейке действительно дата, а не текст, записанный, как дата. Для текста нужно корректировать код

Comment: Спасибо большое все работает. А как надо изменить код, чтобы работало, при нажатии на кнопку, а не при открытии файла?

Comment: Спасибо уже не нужно, допилил сам)

Comment: Не стоит отвечать на подобные вопросы, дабы не способствовать их засилью. Нужен макрос - пусть заказывает у фрилансеров. А здесь задает вопросы, если что-то у самого не получается

Comment: Я понял. Учту в будущем. Согласен, что не корректный вопрос был. И да сам я пытался сделать у меня не получилось....